# Most straightforward way to programatically send Google form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I created a google form with google apps script and would like to have another script I can run to send out the form to a list of e-mail adresses. In the form editor UI I can (by clicking "Send") type in an e-mail adress and the corresponding recipient receives the link to the form. How can I do this programatically? I expected to have a method available but there is nothing like it in the forms documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Use `MailApp`

See the documentation here - https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body

```js
MailApp.sendEmail("recipient@example.com",
                  "Subject",
                  "Content");
```

With your list of emails you could do something like:

```
listOfEmails.forEach(email => {
    MailApp.sendEmail(email,
                  "Subject",
                  "Please fill out this form: " + linkToForm);
})
```

Where `listOfEmails` is an array of strings containing the email addresses, and `linkToForm` is a string of the link to your form.

Comment: this does not yield the same email as the send-button in the editing UI, but I guess there is no way to do it programatically.

Comment: You can send HTML messages with `MailApp` so I suppose you could copy the HTML from the auto generated one and replace the values as needed.